# Mockito non-stubbed functions

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito

I have just started using Mockito, so not very conversant with it. I have mocked an object like this:

```
CInjectorFactory mockFactory = mock(CInjectorFactory.class);
```

Now, if I don't stub a particular function, it doesn't call the original CInjectorFactory's function, and I get a 'null' value:

```
public CMainActivityHelper getMainActivityHelper()
```

Does this mean, that only stubbed functions are available for the mocked object? That this mocked object does not inherit the original functions from the object that is being mocked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
CInjectorFactory mockFactory = mock(CInjectorFactory.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

Then, unstubbed methods will delegate to the real implementation.

Example from the `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` javadoc :

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

 // this calls the real implementation of Foo.getSomething()
 value = mock.getSomething();

 when(mock.getSomething()).thenReturn(fakeValue);

 // now fakeValue is returned
 value = mock.getSomething();
```

Comment: @rajath: Beware that mocked objects with `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` can be a little dangerous, if they use any fields or other instance state--the object will not have its constructor called, nor will the implicit inline-field-initialization happen. With spies, you can actually construct and initialize the object. CALLS_REAL_METHODS can still be handy, though, if your method does not need state or if it operates purely in terms of methods you've mocked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the [documented behavior](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2):

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).

If you want the real methods to be called when not stubbed, you should [spy the real object](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the real methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).

Comment: This worked for me, but I preferred mocking without having to create an instance of the object, which spy required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The front page of the mockito [website](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) clearly shows how to stub method calls:

```
CMainActivityHelper expected = ...;
when(mockFactory.getMainActivityHelper()).thenReturn( expected );
```

Then when you call `mockFactory.getMainActivityHelper()` it will return `expected`.